# Circular dependency issue with Swinject

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, swinject

I'm using Swinject in my Swift iOS app and try doing a circular dependency as explained on the official documentation page: https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/Documentation/CircularDependencies.md

I've copied the code from the circular dependency example and added a few things in the classes, didn't modify anything in the dependency registration code.

Classes and protocols look like this:

```
protocol ParentType: AnyObject {
    func getMyName() -> String
    func getMyChildName() -> String
}

protocol ChildType: AnyObject {
    func getMyName() -> String
    func getMyParentName() -> String
}

class Parent: ParentType {
    let child: ChildType?
    let name = "John"

    init(child: ChildType?) {
        self.child = child
    }

    func getMyName() -> String {
        return name
    }

    func getMyChildName() -> String {
        return child!.getMyName()
    }
}

class Child: ChildType {
    weak var parent: ParentType?
    let name = "John Jr."

    func getMyName() -> String {
        return name
    }

    func getMyParentName() -> String {
        return parent!.getMyName()
    }
}
```

Dependency configuration code looks like this (unchanged from example):

```
let container = Container()
container.register(ParentType.self) { r in
    Parent(child: r.resolve(ChildType.self)!)
}
container.register(ChildType.self) { _ in Child() }
    .initCompleted { r, c in
        let child = c as! Child
        child.parent = r.resolve(ParentType.self)
}
```

The above code is in my AppDelegate's "`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`" function.
Right after the registration code I added this little testing code:

```
let parent = container.resolve(ParentType.self)!
let child = container.resolve(ChildType.self)!
print(parent.getMyName())
print(child.getMyName())
print(parent.getMyChildName())
print(child.getMyParentName())
```

The output is this:

```
John
John Jr.
John Jr.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The error occurs on this line:
`return parent!.getMyName()`

The weird thing is that I placed a breakpoint on that line and this is what happens:

- code stops at the breakpoint
- I look at `self`, it looks correctly initialised, the `parent` property looks correct (a reference to the parent instance)
- I "step over", the error occurs and now the `parent` property is `nil`

Am I doing anything wrong with this circular dependency?

This code is in an "empty" single view iOS app, only with Swinject added as a dependency via Carthage.

XCode version 7.2.1

Swinject version 1.1 installed via Carthage

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because `parent` property of `Child` is defined as a `weak` property.

Let's name the instances like following.

```
let parentA = container.resolve(ParentType.self)!
let childB = container.resolve(ChildType.self)!
```

Here the parent of `childB` is a different instance from `parentA`. Since `parent` property of `childB` is `weak`, it is set to `nil` after `childB` instance is created.

On the other hand, `child` property of `Parent` is a `strong` property. The instance of the `child` of `parentA` is different from `childB`, but the `child` instance is held by `parentA`.

If you need the direct access to a child instance, you can add `var child: ChildType? { get }` to `ParentType` protocol.

Regarding the concept of circular dependency, `parentA`'s `child`'s `parent` is `parentA`, which is the same instance.

If `ParentType` is registered as below,

```
container.register(ParentType.self) { r in
    Parent(child: r.resolve(ChildType.self)!)
}
.inObjectScope(.None)
```

`parentA`'s `child`'s `parent` and `parentA` are different instances.